# CSS position elements along ring of a circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get elements in a formation relative to a circular parent element like so:[image]

Here, there are 5 small squares inside of a larger circle parent. They are equally spaced from each other.

Is there a way to easily make this kind of orientation with JS, CSS, or some other way?
I also wanted this form to be expandable to different number of elements like 6 elements and suc, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: What does the circular parent look like?
Show me the code!

Comment: It may help you : http://jsfiddle.net/yxVkk/